# PHP: What's the best way to check equality of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']?

Tags: php, security

I have a PHP script that checks the HTTP Referer.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://www.example.com/') {...}
```

However, this seems inherintly unsafe ... because what happens if the user goes to `'http://example.com/'` or `'http://www.ExaMple.com'` (both of which don't match the equality test).

**Question**: what's a better equality test to ensure that the HTTP Referer is coming from `'example.com'` ?

Comment: Are you using it for defense? How it can help?

Comment: It's just a first line of defense (especially given I know the referer can be spoofed). It's not protecting anything secure but at the same time, I don't want people abusing my webservice by calling it directly. It's more meant to keep people semi-honest.

Comment: A user can control the http_referer using tamper data.  However, the referer cannot be "forged" to be used in a CSRF attack.

Answer (score 3):

[parse_url()](http://php.net/parse_url) combined with a bit of string juggling should do what you want.  Try this:

```
$url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
//take the last two 'dot segments' of the host
$hostOnly = implode('.',array_slice(explode('.',$url['host']),-2));
if (strtolower($hostOnly) == 'example.com') {
    //stuff
}
```

Note that parse_url() can fail on badly formed URLs, so you might want to add some error checking to be safe.  HTTP_REFERER could easily be filled with junk.

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory response: HTTP_REFERER can be spoofed so there is no way to be 100% sure anyone came from a specific website.

However if you do want to rely on it you can use a regex to look for "example.com" in the HTTP_REFERER. [`stristr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) would also work, and probably would be recommended since it would be faster then a regex. It's also case insensitive so it would match "ExaMple.com" as well as 'example.com".

Comment: (It's still a decent first line of defense, but thanks for mentioning it regardless)

Comment: but wouldn't *stristr* also match on "notmyExample.com" which would be undesirable ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope you don't check it for anything significant.

you can use parse_url() function to get hostname part and to check if HTTP_REFERER contain actually an url.
you can also just substr www. from hostname.
character case is not important as it's always lowercase

or use a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) == 'http://www.example.com/') {...}
```

How about...

```
$parts = explode('/',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
if (in_array('example.com',$parts) || in_array('www.example.com',$parts)) {...}
```

Comment: Not sure this will work all the time because that assumes 1) a trailing slash, 2) that "www." is present instead of the user going directly to http://example.com

Comment: URLs should always be canonicalized, i.e. redirect secondary domain to primary one (when multiple domains are used). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex, this would become

```
if(preg_match("%(http://)?(www\.)?example\.com(/)?%i",$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { ... }
```